# Ubuntu on Sony Vaio UX280p

Tags: wireless, drivers, touchpad

I'm a new Ubuntu user. I just installed the newest version of Ubuntu on my UMPC Sony Vaio UX280P and I have a few problems.

1. WiFi signal is dropped. (2m distance from the router the signal bar is on half)
2. Touchpad works in every movement as a mouse click (dragging or opening folders in every touch) tried THIS:

   But N.5 and N.6 doesn't work....

   INSTRUCTIONS (run from terminal as root):

   1. Copy mouse.tar.gz to /usr/src: `cp mouse.tar.gz /usr/src`
   2. Go to /usr/src: `cd /usr/src`
   3. Gunzip it, and untar it: `tar xzvf mouse.tar.gz`
   4. Add the new module to DKMS: `dkms add -m psmouse -v ux`
   5. Build the new kernel module through DKMS: `dkms build -m psmouse -v ux`
   6. Install the new kernel module through DKMS: `dkms install -m psmouse -v ux`
   7. Remove the psmouse module from the running kernel: `modprobe -r psmouse`
   8. Activate the newly created psmouse module: `modprobe psmouse`
3. touchscreen and camera don't work. (I probably just need drivers, but I don't know where to find them. (I will do more when I have the time, that's not a big deal)

The most important thing is to fix WiFi and Touchpad sticking.